# OAUTH: Authorization Code Grant Example in C# .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, docusignapi

We have a legacy solution that currently has to be based in Framework as opposed to Core. We have successfully developed a working version in the DocuSign sandbox environment using temporary tokens to authenticate. Now that we need to goto Prod, we need to integrate OAUTH properly.

I'm currently banging my head against the wall trying to locate a .NET Framework example of how to accomplish authorization code grant using the DocuSign API. I found multiple examples in the Developer Center, but of course for this particular project we are limited to .NET Framework, and I haven't been able to locate anything specific to it.

I have run the Core eg03 example that is provided on the Docusign Developer Center, and it works fine, but has a lot of Core-only stuff in it that I'm not advanced enough to backport into Framework. It also seems possibly overly-complicated for what we need. I just need a simple way to request a token and use it.

Our use case is pretty straightforward -- just using the API to do an embedded signing ceremony based on a Template. As I mentioned, it's working fine with the temp token. Would just like to find a starting point to use as a basis for proper auth code grant in .NET Framework.

Has anyone looked into this? Is it possible? Thank you in advance for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advances of .Net Core is that it includes support for OAuth.

I certainly understand that you are limited to Framework.

What OAuth flow will you be using. If the person who will be signing the embedded signing ceremony has their own DocuSign user account, then you'd probably use OAuth Authorization Code Grant.

If the signer does NOT have a DocuSign account (a common use case for enabling customers/partners/etc to sign) then you should use OAuth JWT Grant to enable your application to **impersonate** a DocuSign *system* account (eg "sales@example.com).

**Implementing Authorization Code Grant** is specific to the web framework that you're using with .Net Framework because the OAuth flow involves redirecting the user's browser and also making an HTTPS call to DocuSign's identity server.

You'll need to google for "oauth authorization code grant name_of_your_web_framework"

**DocuSign does have an example for implementing JWT Grant in .Net Framework.** See https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, but it looks like all the "legacy" code on github has now been replaced with .NET Core MVC samples.  This is where I was directed to: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp.  Please don't leave developers who have to maintain older systems out in the cold.  Thanks!

Comment: Which web framework are you using? MVC or something else?

Comment: .Net Framework and WebForms.  My client writes the web pages in VB while I do the backend and supporting libraries in C#.

Comment: Thank you @RandyB. We will look into providing a webforms / .Net Framework example. But that won't be within a month or probably more. Meanwhile see this [post](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Implementing-OAuth-for-ASP.NET-Web-Forms) and this [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+oauth+to+.net+webforms)

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I already have my authorization working from way back, but I'm researching another issue and wanted to start with DocuSign sample code which matched our configuration to see what we're doing wrong.. Several months ago, I could find it, but now it's all been replaced.  I'll probably start a new question about issues with this new sample code not working as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm also looking for an ASP.NET MVC solution. I have found a small note in the documentation about the subject and a code file inside the  .NET Core MVC samples. However, no working example. Documentation: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/c-sharp/auth/ Code file: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/Common/AuthCodeGrant.cs

Comment: Good news, we (DocuSign) are getting ready to publish a .Net Framework MVC code example that uses OAuth Authorize Code grant. We'll publish a [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers) when it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DocuSign Visual Studio extension - see [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.DocuSignVSExtension][1]

I have successfully used it to add DocuSign Code Grant (and JWT Grant) support to an existing application.

I made a few adjustments:

1. I do not use the DSOwinStartup class. Instead, I have moved the initialization code to the existing startup class.
2. I have added missing configuration values to web.config.

P.S. I had to disable ReSharper to make the extension work.

Answer (score 0):

We now have a .Net Framework DocuSign Authorization Code grant example. See the [repo](https://github.com/docusign/code-example-net-framework-auth-code-grant)